# Como abrir um aplicativo com Speech Recognition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automatização

Eu gostaria de criar um mini aplicativo que abra um arquivo ou até mesmo outro aplicativo por meio de speech recognition, ou seja, eu abriria ele e quando desse o comando exemplo:

```
if 'open' in command:
    talk('Openning program')
    # código da ação de abrir o programa
```

Podemos descartar a parte da função do código acima, visto que já está setada. Só gostaria de saber qual library e qual comando seriam pra ação de abrir um programa a partir de outro.

Agradeço toda ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir um arquivo no OS — usando o programa padrão dele — utilize a função `startfile` do módulo `os`, passando como argumento o caminho do arquivo que você deseja abrir, junto com a extensão do arquivo. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = microfone.listen(source)

try:
    text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language = "pt-BR").lower()
    if text.startswith("abrir"): os.startfile(text.split(maxsplit = 1)[-1])

except: 
    print("Parece que houve algum problema no reconhecimento da voz...")
```